# Сделать, чтобы при QTreeWidget.sortByColumn(DescendingOrder) пустое значение было сверху?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6, qtreewidget

Есть `QTreeWidget`, мне его нужно отсортировать по убыванию значений в столбце, в котором может содержаться пустое значение.
Однако, при стандартном конструкте `treeWidget.sortByColumn(2, Qt.SortOrder.DescendingOrder)` - при сортировке пустое значение улетает вниз.

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы сортировка по прежнему была по убыванию, однако пустые значения высвечивались сверху?
Или же единственным вариантом будет задать условное `zzzzz!!FIX_ME!!zzzzz` для каждого пустого значения столбца перед сортировкой?

Накидал элементарный пример:

**ui_one_button.py**:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(335, 187)
        MainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LayoutDirection.LeftToRight)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(254, 214, 188);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.treeWidget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget(parent=self.centralwidget)
        self.treeWidget.setObjectName("treeWidget")
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        item_0 = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treeWidget)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.treeWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.treeWidget.headerItem().setText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.treeWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "c"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "a"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(1).setText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(2).setText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "New Item"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(2).setText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "b"))
        self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(2).setText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.treeWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
```

**main_one_button.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from ui_one_button import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

# Собственно, тот самый sort:
        self.treeWidget.sortByColumn(2, Qt.SortOrder.DescendingOrder)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо перегрузить оператор `<` для элементов (именно он для сравнения значений при сортировке и используется)

примеры перегрузки на `pyqt5` и на `c++` [можете посмотреть тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363200/is-it-possible-to-sort-numbers-in-a-qtreewidget-column)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.